# How a batch file can delete itself and exit the command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is that anyway I can write a batch can delete itself, with exit the command prompt?
I have no idea how to do this. If I delete that batch first, then exit cannot run. If I exit first, then I won't able to delete the batch.... Can I do this within the same batch file ? Thanks for any clue!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following command line as last line in your batch file:

```
del "%~f0" & exit
```

This line contains two commands on one line:

- **DEL** for deleting the batch file and
- **EXIT** for exiting command process.

The operator `&` results in execution of second command independent on result of first command. For more details about usage of multiple commands on one line see for example [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343351/).

Comment: Wow!! The "& exit" trick works!!! Thanks a lot!! =D